# Software AG: how to make local integration server accessible?

Tags: configuration, integration, esb, soa, webmethods

I installed Software AG Integration Server instance in my laptop. Now, i want another laptop(which is already set in the same network) to access this integration server through IP address. I set the user management(created user and group) and added ACLs in IS Admin Console, but nothing worked. What else should be set to make it work?

Comment: Did you checked the Windows-Firewall? By default it will block the access to port 5555 and you need to add an Rule to allow the Access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir.